# Salt and Hash Sage Pay Token

Tags: payment-gateway, opayo

We are using the Sage Pay Token system so that customers can easily pay for items in the future. (This is a public facing website)

When Sage Pay returns a token (to allow us to make future payments) should that token be stored in plain text or should it be salt and hashed?

Comment: Hashing is a one-way process. You would need to *encrypt* it so you could *decrypt* it back to the original token value. But has been pointed out, there is no need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in plain text - it's only good for use via Sage Pay, and via your own vendor account.